# rails 301 redirect for resources with path option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, routes

I have routes like this

```
resources :people, :path => "designers", :only => [:index, :show] do
  member do
    post 'add_favorite_designer'
    post 'remove_favorite_designer'
  end
end
```

I can use both of `example.com/people` and `example.com/designers`.However I want to `example.com/people` redirect with **301 code** to `example.com/designers` and I want to implement it for all resources with path option.Is there any way to automate it ?

Answer (score 1):

The path `/people` should not be available anymore because it's been replaced by `/designers` when you use the `:path` parameters.

If you want to redirect all requests from `/people` to `/designers`, use

```
match '/people/*action', to: redirect {|p, req| "/designers/#{p[:action]}" }
```